# Piping a node.js script's stdout to another's stdin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

*In case you are not familiar with CoffeeScript, [here](https://gist.github.com/puzzl3r/494db8c4b4caf05faad3)'s the JavaScript version of `p1.coffee` and `p2.coffee` mentioned below.*

Piping a node.js script's `stdout` to another's stdin doesn't seem to work. I have `p1.coffee` which outputs numbers to `stdout` as fast as it can:

```
i = 0
(->
    i += 1
    process.stdout.write "#{i} "
    )() while true
```

I now have `p2.coffee` which does exactly what's like a `cat`:

```
process.stdin.on 'end', -> console.log "EOF"
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Now if I pipeline them together, it displays only the first number and "blocks" there:

```
> coffee p1.coffee | coffee p2.coffee
1
```

I'm using node v0.10.31 on Windows if that matters.

Comment: you do write some weirrrd code. why not simply `loop \n i+= 1 \n process.stdout.write i`? no need to create a function on each iteration. you can tell from the tortured syntax that it's wrong. keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

That might be a **Windows** specific issue. I tried the following with **Node.js v0.10.31** on **OS X** and it worked fine:

```
// cat.js

process.stdin.once('end', function () {
    console.log('EOF');
});
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);
```

```
// count.js

var i = 0;
while (true) {
    process.stdout.write(i++ + ' ');
}
```

and piped the output of **count.js** to **cat.js**:

```
node count.js | node cat.js
```

---

Also note that your CoffeeScript compiles to:

```
var i;

i = 0;

while (true) {
  (function() {
    i += 1;
    return process.stdout.write("" + i + " ");
  })();
}
```

Creating functions within loops makes your code slower. You could do the following instead:

```
i = 0
loop process.stdout.write("#{i += 1} ")
```